# Vertical Center on responsive layout

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the class .vertical-align-center on a content div inside a bootstrap 3 column.

If the height of the column is fixed, so it is bigger than the content height, or if the other column in the same row has bigger content that makes the height bigger than the content, all works fine.

But on smaller devices, I have the column width set to 12, so the column has a fluid height that is the same as the content. This makes the content go off -50% from the top instead.

Any ideas how to solve this?

```css
.vertical-align-center {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="column col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
  <div class="column-content vertical-align-center">
    <h3>Heading</h3>
    <p>Some text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Use media queries matching the Boostrap `sm` ones to "undo" the vertical alignment styles and restore normal behaviour.

Comment: Thanks, but I need a more general solution and it will not always be the case that I want to "undo" vertical alignment for bootstrap sm.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `flex` for this solution. Like

```css
body,html {
  height: 100%;
}

.Aligner {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="Aligner">
  <div class="Aligner-item">
    <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione, qui.</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sed itaque voluptatum fuga aspernatur consectetur ipsum porro corporis autem commodi totam beatae atque doloremque possimus hic sunt, dolores ullam quod ducimus.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If the content is taller than the view (eg. add a few more `<p>`s to your example), then the top will be above the viewport and you can't scroll to see it.

Comment: you can remove height from body,html in this case. We don't use height on content area so you can remove in future.

Comment: I have set height because i want to show its working or not?

Comment: That doesn't change the fact that the element will stay aligned to the centre, even if it expands beyond the top of the screen.

Comment: It screws up the layout for all the children elements, they act like they were inline elements.